# Sending Alt-F5 to Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop

I am trying to use Visual Studio Code's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> shortcut on a remote desktop, but it only works if I configure the remote desktop to apply windows key combinations on the remote computer. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> is not a windows key combination that I'm aware of. What does it do, if anything? But more importantly, is there a good way to force this keypress to be sent to the remote system without configuring all windows key combinations to be sent to the remote system? I still want to use <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> to switch local desktops without having to un-maximize the remote desktop first. It seems <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> should be going to the remote system since it doesn't do anything in Windows. Is my best option to re-map my Visual Studio Code keyboard shortcut to something else? How do I know which key combinations will be considered windows combinations that will not make it to the remote system?

Answer (score 1):

You could just go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts and change the shortcut there to something you can already do.

Comment: Yes, that was an option I mentioned at the end of my question, so I already knew about that option. It seems like there should be a better way and some explanation of why Alt-F5 isn't being sent.